# why /var/log/wtmp and /var/log/lastlog have read permission for other users?

Tags: linux, unix

In my Linux server lastlog and wtmp files have read permission set for other users (664) . Do we really need to keep the read permission for other users or can I change it to (660 or 640) . Does it affect anything in the server like some command execution and all ?

Answer (score 2):

Since those files contain a record of who logged in and from where they are needed if want tools like `last` , `who` and `w` etc. to work.

AFAIK those files also contain the info that some login shells display
*"last login from user NAME was on DATE-TIME from IP/host"*
which is a useful security feature that allows users to monitor their own account for abuse.

I would keep the permissions on [`wtmp`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/wtmp) and [lastlog](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lastlog) as they are.

Comment: So if we remove the permission for reading for others , does it make the commands fail for other non-root users ?

Comment: Yes indeed that happen

Comment: In one of my servers lastlog has some how 000 permission ..I don't know how .. But still last,w and who is displaying info .. So I am getting little confused here . wtmp have 664 though .